# EmberJS - generate random object in array of objects

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a button that when clicked loads a new route in my Ember site and returns an array of objects. What I would like to do is set it so that this button being clicked results in a random object in that array being rendered in the template. That way the user can get a different result with every click. I am not sure how to tell it to select a random index and render it in my handlebars template. Any help would be appreciated. I am pretty new to Ember.

This is my route that is being loaded (but doesn't show the content):

```
App.GenerateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.GENERATE;
    }
 });


App.GENERATE = [
    {
    id: 1,
    word: //word here,
    language: //language here',
    trans: //translation here'
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    word: //word here,
    language: //language here',
    trans: //translation here'
    },
    {
    id: 3,
    word: //word here,
    language: //language here',
    trans: //translation here'
    }
];
```

Comment: you want to select a random object from the array and render into handlebars ? or shuffle the array randomly and display the entire array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use handlebars to achieve this.
Pass the model to the handlebars function and then with a little javascript magic, select a random object from the array and then render.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('randomize', function(myArray, options) {

  return myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)].id;
});
```

And you call the helper method in this way -

```
{{ randomize model}}
```

[Demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jedixiqeka/1/edit?html,js,output)

A random object is returned every time you refresh or hit the `route`